# JavaScript object data and Arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object as follows.

```
var sampleData = {
    "studentsList": {
        "Student1": {
            "marks": "123",
            "grade": "B"
        },
        "Student2": {
            "marks": "144",
            "grade": "A"
        }
    }
};​
```

Now the user enters the name of a student, say `Student1` and I need to get the details of that object.

**I have two questions.**

**[1]** How do I get the details of the entered student using JavaScript?

When I use `sampleData.studendsList.valueOf("Student1")` returns me the complete object. I just need the details of "Student1".

**[2]** Is this the correct way to do it? Or we should create an array of Students and that contains an property called "name" with value say `Student1` ? If I go with this approach then I need to iterate through the entire array list to get the details of a student.

Which appraoch is better?

Comment: There are *no* Arrays present in the above code. A better way would be to structure it to *use* Arrays as they are the more natural structure here.

Comment: You don't really need to have a `sampleData` variable wrapping the array if you don't have any other sample data. You could just have `var studentsList = {blah}`.

Comment: @pst, In the above example, I don't have an array. But I can have an array of Students and name can be one attribute in that array. I think it is the best way to represent it, but performance wise, I'm not sure if that is the right approach to go by.

Comment: @Apps O(n) is only generally applicable when n increases to "a non-small value". Unless there is a performance concern, represent the data as is best fit for the current problem. It is very easy to create a cross-lookup from an Array or to Sort object properties based on their corresponding values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array is usually the more natural way to store a list of items (like students). But there are tradeoffs. As structured (using objects), you can access any student by name in constant time:

```
sampleData.studentsList.Student1
```

Structuring with an array looks like this:

```
var sampleData = {
    "studentsList": [
        {
            "marks": "123",
            "grade": "B"
        },
        {
            "marks": "144",
            "grade": "A"
        }
    ]
};​
```

Access the `nth` student like this:

```
sampleData.studentsList[n]
```

If the index of the desired student is not known, then accessing a particular student (based on its details) is `O(n)` (because you'd need to iterate the entire array to find the correct item in the worst case).

Answer (score 2):

`sampleData.studentsList.Student1` OR `sampleData.studentsList["Student1"]`

Answer (score 1):

**[1]**  Access the property by using the access via `[]`. That way you can insert a variable there instead of just a hardcoded identifier.

```
var studentDetails = sampleData.studendsList[ "Student1" ];
```

**[2]** For fast access to a specific student, this the better approach imo. Any array would involve some kind of array scanning to access a specific details object.

Answer (score 1):

**[1]** given a student name stored in a javascript variable, let's call it `studentName`, you would access that student's details like so:

```
var studentData = sampleData.studentsList[studentName];
```

**[2]** the big determining factor when choosing between an array or an object is: what does the key mean? if the key is irrelevant or just numeric, it should be an array. in this case, the key is the name of a student, so having an object is definitely the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT... I just realized that you're just building the object in place (rather than having it as a String)... so in fact you can skip the parsing and just get to the object directly via..

```
sampleData.studentsList.Student1
```

If however you had that object in the exact shape you have it but as a String you'd need to JSON.parse it first like so...

```
 myObj = JSON.parse(yourString);

    myObj.studentsList.Student1
```